# Replace all occurrences of characters in Angular binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to replace all occurrences of certain characters in my angular binding. The characters that I'd like to remove are:

- dashes (-)
- greater than (>)

So a string like `--->John Doe` would end up displaying like `John Doe`

in my view I bind my value and try and replace all those occurrences like so:

```
{{person.name.replace(/-/g, '').replace(/>/g, '')}}
```

But when I run the code I get the following error:

> Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '/' not a primary
>   expression at column 22 of the expression [person.name.replace(/-/g,
>   '').replace(/>/g, '')] starting at [/-/g, '').replace(/>/g, '')].

Any pointers on what to do in this scenario?

Comment: Can you add a demo on jsfiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

would be better if you use filters rather than writing code in dom .

```
app.filter('myFilter ', function() {
  return function(input) {
    return input.replace(/-/g, '').replace(/>/g, '');
  };
});

{{person.name | myFilter }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ain't a angularjs expert but what i want to say is you are manipulating stuff in your view which is a wrong approach .I made a [simple plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4q8E9USH4m6c8fpVSjFg)  to solve this problem using simple string replace function .

```
 $scope.person.name = 'r->m';
 $scope.replaceString = function(data){
 return data.replace(/-/g, '').replace(/>/g, '');}
```

and display it .

```
   <p> {{ replaceString(person.name) }}</p>
```

you can check [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/4q8E9USH4m6c8fpVSjFg) .